# dynamic triggering of "javascript:__doPostBack()"

Tags: javascript, asp.net, perl, postback

I have a web page which is written in asp and there is a a delete function for a specific item.

The delete button is using "javascript:__doPostBack()".  i need to implement some kind of automation to trigger this button for each item.. what is the right way to do this in perl?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I've had success in this process before by using code along these lines:

```
// You'll have to change this, of course.
var deleteButton = document.getElementByid("whatever");

// Now that I have the button:
// Call the function, make sure it gets the right `this`.
__doPostBack.call(deleteButton);
```

Comment: The link has no id unfortunately, the link is implemented as :


    '<a href="javascript:__doPostBack('GridView1','Delete$0')"    style="color:#333333;">Del--</a>'

Comment: Sounds like you should be looking at xpaths. I'm on my phone or I'd post a link.